# SQL query reporting what I think is the wrong min value using min aggregate and where operator to filter

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, where-clause, min

I am taking an SQL course on coursera and this question came up on a practice quiz

"Excluding $0.00, what is the minimum bi-weekly high rate of pay (please include the dollar sign and decimal point in your answer)?

Now I got the right answer (Which returned $100.00) using

```
SELECT 
    min(Biweekly_High_Rate)
FROM
    salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE Biweekly_High_Rate <> '$0.00'
```

however, when I query using SELECT * from the same table, I can see that, at least in the rows retrieved, that there is a value of $15.00 which is less than $100.00. Why is it not returning $15.00? [table snip of SELECT * FROM salary_range_by_job_classification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58fdR.png)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (postgres, sqlite, mysql, etc)? I find it odd you can aggregate on a string value like "$0.00". Usually you would need to convert it into a number first

Comment: I am using sqlite

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend removing the dollar sign and converting the resultant string to a decimal amount. Enter a decimal amount as your limiting parameter (`0.00`) as well, so you are comparing two numbers, not two strings. This should result in something more expected:

```
SELECT MIN(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),REPLACE(BiWeekly_High_Rate,'$','')))
FROM salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),REPLACE(BiWeekly_High_Rate,'$','')) <> 0.00
```

See how that goes. If you compare two strings, you are asking for (I think) the first value *alphabetically* by using the `MIN` aggregation.

Comment: I tired removing the $ before posting. It just yielded 0.  In your query segment, my current RDBMS is treating DECIMAL as a function and saying it does not exist and this results in an error. I have a feeling some of my issues have to do with the platform I'm using (sqlite). P.S. I am quite new to SQL so I am curious about the CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2) line. Why choose 10 and 2?

Comment: The choice of (10,2) was fairly arbitrary - I saw you had two decimal places used, hence the 2 - the rest will just give 8 digits of space to the left of the decimal place and it seemed enough :) I don't know about the failure of `CONVERT(DECIMAL...` - you could perhaps replace it with `CAST(REPLACE(BiWeekly_High_Rate,'$','') AS DECIMAL(10,2))` instead? Worth Googling the limitations of SQL light, I guess - I don't have that knowledge.

Comment: Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT Min(Cast(Replace(biweekly_high_rate, '$', '') AS REAL))
FROM   salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE  biweekly_high_rate <> '$0.00'
```